# Backbone Collection not being included in JSON string when using JSON.stringify on model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am having an issue where my collection property (in this case Parameters Collection) in my model is not being included in the JSON string created by the JSON.stringify function. Is there any reason why this might be happening? It basically just excludes it and adds the rest of the variables to the JSON string.

Here is the event:

```
                EventAggregator.on('toggleFacet', function (facets) {
                var facets = SearchOptionsUtil.getCheckedFacets(facets);
                var sortOptions = SearchOptionsUtil.getSortOptions();

                var searchOptions = new SearchOptionsModel();

                for(var facet in facets){
                    var id = facet;
                    var value = facets[facet];
                    searchOptions.parameters.add(new ParameterModel({id: id, values: value.split(',')}));
                }

                var criteria = $.extend(facets, sortOptions);
                location.hash = UriUtil.getUriHash(criteria);

                RequestUtil.requestSearchResults(searchOptions);
            });
```

Here is the fetch:

```
requestSearchResults: function (searchOptions) {
            //fetch the results
            var performSearchModel = new PerformSearchModel();
            var searchOptionsJson = JSON.stringify(searchOptions);
            performSearchModel.fetch({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({searchOptionsJson: searchOptionsJson}),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("Inside success");
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (errorResponse) {
                    console.log("Inside Failure")
                    console.log(errorResponse.responseText)
                }
            })  //have to wait for the fetch to complete
                .complete(function () {

                    //show our regions
                    App.facetsRegion.show(new FacetListView({collection: performSearchModel.facets}));
                    App.resultsRegion.show(new ResultListView({collection: performSearchModel.results}));

                    //perform search fetch complete
                });
        }
```

and here is the model:

```
var SearchOptionsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            parameters: ParameterCollection,
            currentItemId: '{EE8AA76E-0A3E-437B-84D8-AD7FCBAF2928}',
            sortBy: 0,
            sortDirection: 'asc',
            resultsPerPage: 10
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.parameters = new ParameterCollection();

            //fetch calls an on change event.
            this.on("change", this.fetchCollections);
        },
        url: function () {
            return '/Services/Search/SearchService.asmx/SearchOptions';
        },
        parse: function (response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
            return data;
        },
        fetchCollections: function () {
            //when we call fetch for the model we want to fill its collections
            this.parameters.set(
                _(this.get("parameters")).map(function (parameter) {
                    return new ParameterModel(parameter);
                })
            );
        }
    });
```

UPDATE**

So I changed the way I create and add the parameters collection in the SearchOptionsModel and the JSON object is being formed correctly. I changed it from this:

```
 var searchOptions = new SearchOptionsModel();

            for(var facet in facets){
                var id = facet;
                var value = facets[facet];
                searchOptions.parameters.add(new ParameterModel({id: id, values: value.split(',')}));
            }
```

To this:

```
                 var parameters = new ParameterCollection();

                //loop through all of the variables in this object
                for(var facet in facets){
                    var id = facet;
                    var value = facets[facet];

                    parameters.add(new ParameterModel({id: id, values: value.split(',')}));
                }

                var searchOptions = new SearchOptionsModel({parameters: parameters});
```

Now the parameters are filled under the attributes in the model and I see an empty parameters variable on the searchOptions object (which was being filled before instead). Why is there a parameters variable set in the SearchOptionsModel if I am not explicitly creating it? Is it because the parameters default is set to a collection?

Comment: Have you checked that `parameters` is correct when `JSON.stringify` gets hit?  I wonder if the problem might be that the async call to `fetchCollections` is wiping out what gets added from "facets".

Comment: I looked at that and the parameters object was being filled, I updated the question with a solution, although it did lead to another question..

Answer (score 0):

To convert a Backbone model to JSON, you must use the `toJSON` method:

```
model.toJSON();
```

Check doc here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Comment: Calling `JSON.stringify` will automatically call `toJSON` on the object passed to it (if the method exists).